# Sql query using multiple left outer joins taking more time to complete

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create materialized view MV_SD_SIPL_BOMLEVELSALT_5 refresh force on demand as 
(
select 'id-' || rownum id, 
                t1.L1 l0, t1.L0 l1, t1.alternateitem l1ai, t1.effstartdate l1sd, t1.effenddate l1ed, t1.qtyper l1q, t1.siteid l1s, t1.transittime l1tt,
                t2.l0 l2,  t2.alternateitem l2ai, t2.effstartdate l2sd, t2.effenddate l2ed, t2.qtyper l2q, t2.siteid l2s, t2.transittime l2tt,
                t3.l0 l3,  t3.alternateitem l3ai, t3.effstartdate l3sd, t3.effenddate l3ed, t3.qtyper l3q, t3.siteid l3s,t3.transittime l3tt,
                t4.l0 l4, t4.alternateitem l4ai, t4.effstartdate l4sd, t4.effenddate l4ed, t4.qtyper l4q, t4.siteid l4s,t4.transittime l4tt,
                t5.l0 l5, t5.alternateitem l5ai, t5.effstartdate l5sd, t5.effenddate l5ed, t5.qtyper l5q, t5.siteid l5s,t5.transittime l5tt,
                t6.l0 l6, t6.alternateitem l6ai, t6.effstartdate l6sd, t6.effenddate l6ed, t6.qtyper l6q, t6.siteid l6s,t6.transittime l6tt,
                t7.l0 l7, t7.alternateitem l7ai, t7.effstartdate l7sd, t7.effenddate l7ed, t7.qtyper l7q, t7.siteid l7s,t7.transittime l7tt,
                t8.l0 l8, t8.alternateitem l8ai, t8.effstartdate l8sd, t8.effenddate l8ed, t8.qtyper l8q, t8.siteid l8s,t8.transittime l8tt,
                t9.l0 l9, t9.alternateitem l9ai, t9.effstartdate l9sd, t9.effenddate l9ed, t9.qtyper l9q, t9.siteid l9s,t9.transittime l9tt,
                t10.l0 l10, t10.alternateitem l10ai, t10.effstartdate l10sd, t10.effenddate l10ed, t10.qtyper l10q, t10.siteid l10s,t10.transittime l10tt,
                t11.l0 l11, t11.alternateitem l11ai, t11.effstartdate l11sd, t11.effenddate l11ed, t11.qtyper l11q, t11.siteid l11s,t11.transittime l11tt,
                nvl2(t1.L0, 1, 0) + nvl2(t1.L0, 1, 0) + nvl2(t2.l0, 1, 0) +
                nvl2(t3.l0, 1, 0) + nvl2(t4.l0, 1, 0) + nvl2(t5.l0, 1, 0) +
                nvl2(t6.l0, 1, 0) + nvl2(t7.l0, 1, 0) + nvl2(t8.l0, 1, 0) +
                nvl2(t9.l0, 1, 0) + nvl2(t10.l0, 1, 0) + nvl2(t11.l0, 1, 0) cnt,
                t1.l1 sku,
                t1.bomid
  from (select L1, L0, alternateitem,effstartdate,effenddate, qtyper,siteid,fromsiteid,bomid,
   transittime  from MV_SD_SIPL_BOMLEVELSALT55 where l1 like 'SD%') t1
  left outer join MV_SD_SIPL_BOMLEVELSALT55 t2 on t1.alternateitem = t2.l1 and t1.fromsiteid = t2.siteid
  left outer join MV_SD_SIPL_BOMLEVELSALT55 t3 on t2.alternateitem = t3.l1 and t2.fromsiteid = t3.siteid
  left outer join MV_SD_SIPL_BOMLEVELSALT55 t4 on t3.alternateitem = t4.l1 and t3.fromsiteid = t4.siteid
  left outer join MV_SD_SIPL_BOMLEVELSALT55 t5 on t4.alternateitem = t5.l1 and t4.fromsiteid = t5.siteid
  left outer join MV_SD_SIPL_BOMLEVELSALT55 t6 on t5.alternateitem = t6.l1 and t5.fromsiteid = t6.siteid
  left outer join MV_SD_SIPL_BOMLEVELSALT55 t7 on t6.alternateitem = t7.l1 and t6.fromsiteid = t7.siteid
  left outer join MV_SD_SIPL_BOMLEVELSALT55 t8 on t7.alternateitem = t8.l1 and t7.fromsiteid = t8.siteid
  left outer join MV_SD_SIPL_BOMLEVELSALT55 t9 on t8.alternateitem = t9.l1 and t8.fromsiteid = t9.siteid
  left outer join MV_SD_SIPL_BOMLEVELSALT55 t10 on t9.alternateitem = t10.l1 and t9.fromsiteid = t10.siteid
  left outer join MV_SD_SIPL_BOMLEVELSALT55 t11 on t10.alternateitem = t11.l1 and t10.fromsiteid = t11.siteid
);
```

I have this above query to create Materialized view,its taking around 50 minutes to complete. Please help me to reduce the timings.. I tried to create normal index and even tried to rewrite the query but its not helping. Explain Plan is attached, please help me to tune the query. Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is much you could do about. The query itself does nothing wrong. Maybe consider rethinking your model.

Comment: @FreshPrince.. Its Oracle...

Comment: @LinusCaldwell.. I tried to run through full outer join and instead of refereng all columns from the MV_SD_SIPL_BOMLEVELSALT55, i tried to select only required columns but not much improved in the run time.. please suggest me if any other way to write the query..

Answer (score 1):

**First Point**

When you said

> I tried to create normal index

What did you mean? Can you show us the indexes you have created?
I'm pretty sure there is an index you forgot.
The list of column you need index on :

```
l1, alternateitem, fromsiteid, and siteid
```

**Second point**

This is bad:

```
from 
(
    select L1, L0, alternateitem,effstartdate,effenddate, qtyper,siteid,fromsiteid,bomid, transittime  
    from MV_SD_SIPL_BOMLEVELSALT55 
    where l1 like 'SD%'
) t1
```

Why are you making a subquery here? Just filter the clause:

```
select  bablabla
from MV_SD_SIPL_BOMLEVELSALT55 as t1
    left outer join blablabla
where t1.l1 like 'SD%'
```

Comment: i already tried to add index with columns (l1, alternateitem, fromsiteid, and siteid) but it dint help much, just reduced some 4-5 minutes..